# Hide div if li id is blank

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I need to hide the `div` if the `li` is blank

```
<div>
  <ul>
   <li id=“item1”></li>
   <li></li>
   </ul>
</div>

$(document).ready(function () {
$(‘#div’).onchange(function() {
    if (‘#div’).text === ‘’) {
   $(‘li#item1).hide();
} else {
   $(‘li#item1).show();
});
```

If the user changes their age the list displays different items. I need to hide the div if the li’s in the list are blank. So if the user changes their selection how do I reload function onchange?

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
   $(‘#div’).filter(function() {
    if (‘li#item1’).text.change === ‘’) {
    $(‘#div’).hide();
    } else {
    $(‘#div’).show();
  });
```

Not sure can I filter a .change function?

```
$(document).ready(function ({
   $('body').change(function() {
   if ($(li#item1).text(); !== '') {
   $(‘#div’).hide();
    } else {
   $(‘#div’).show();
  }) 
});
```

Would something like this work?

Comment: Check error thrown in browser dev tools console. There is no jQuery `onchange` method and you should see error thrown. Also there is no change event on `<div>`

Comment: There is no `onchange()` method in jQuery; you may have meant to type [`change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/), which does exist, but why do you believe your `<div>` will have ever fire, or detect, a `change` event since there are no form elements or inputs within? Further you have invalid HTML since an `<li>` must be a child element of either a `<ul>` or `<ol>` element.

Comment: So what would recommend using if there is no onchange if the user changes their selection and need to reload the function again?

Answer (score 1):

You are using typographic quote characters all over in your code(`‘’`, `“item1”` etc.) - this won't work. Change all those quotes to "simple" quotes. Also, in your if/else condition, the selectors (`$('li#item1')...`) are missing the closing quote. Also, having a `li` as a child of a `div` is invalid HTML. And there's no `onchange()` method in jQuery...

Answer (score -1):

Offcourse it wont't work. The onchange() event -in javascript (in jQuery is the change()) only work in the select, input and text area element - not a div:
[image]

Comment: Can I use .change instead of .onchange?

Comment: As i said, change() event only work in input, select and text area element - not div! So answer is no - it still not work!

Comment: @Az3492 i think you can use another approach. As i understand, you are using jQuery to change the content of the list elemets and you want to hide list item with empty content right? **In that case**, you can create a function _for example_ hideEmpty() to hide empty list items. And every time you made chnge to the list content - **call the hideEmpty()** follow along with!

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: @Az3492 this is my example for **hideEmplty** function: `function hideEmpty(){
    var items = $('#div_ID li');
    for (let i = 0; i<= items.length; i++){
        $(items[i]).show();
        if($(items[i]).text() === ''){
            $(items[i]).hide();
    }
 }
    
}` and after make cahnge to any list's item just simple call this function for example: `$('#li_01").text('What ever'); hideEmpty();`